# YouTube API: request both "Date Published" and "Date Uploaded"

Tags: json, web-scraping, google-sheets, youtube-api

I've got an extensive Google Spreadsheet following all of my businesses videos and statistics. One piece of data I always keep is both the publish date and upload date of a video since we upload our videos weeks before hand and publish them later. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find *any* JSON feed that will give me an "uploadedAt" date, only "publishedAt", I have to manually copy this data from the videos "info" page.

Similarly, the other piece of data that would be handy to automatically scrape would be the "Raw File" line, as I also keep track of unofficial project titles.

I'm suspecting that neither of these stats are possible to scrape, but if anyone has found anything, that would be extremely useful!

Comment: Yes, you can only use the `publishedAt`. Note that this time might be different than the time that the video was uploaded. There's no available parameter that you can use.

Comment: It has to be there, somewhere, Google's analytics shows the creation date. The API lists it as "creationTime" under the "fileDetails" part, but when I run that it only displays the original filename, and no other info. Youtube is starting to bury the creation date more and more with each UI update, and its taking me longer and longer to retrieve the necessary info. Amnesty International developed a program that retries YouTube video EXACT creation dates in order to expose Russian bots, it's a neat web program, but I would like to implement that myself.